# Javascript Iteration- Reversing Order

Tags: javascript, iteration, reverse

This is for some homework of mine. Javascript has thus so far been the most difficult for me to grasp. Here's a copy of my assignment:
Copy the following code into new file.

```
<html>>
<body>
<script>
var namIn = window.prompt("Enter Senator’s State and FULL Name, separated by space:" );
var namAr = namIn.split("");
var namArLen = namAr.length;
document.write(namAr + "<br /> Length:" + namArLen); 
</script> </body>
</html>
```

When you execute this code you will see that after you entered your name it was loaded into namAr array. Your output will look like this:

```
C,o,l,o,r,a,d,o, ,M,a,r,k, ,U,d,a,l,l 
Length: 19
```

Your task:
Add a small iteration that will display your name in reverse order. For example if senator’s state and name as I entered as:

```
Colorado Mark Udall
```

your output will be

```
C,o,l,o,r,a,d,o, ,M,a,r,k, ,U,d,a,l,l 
Length: 19
lladU kraM odaroloC
```

I'm trying to achieve the bold part. They check our coding. I'm not looking for an answer as much as I am a sort of walkthrough or explaination. Anything help, thanks!

RESOLVED
Figured it out, thanks! All great answers- you guys are so smart!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var namIn = window.prompt("Enter Senator’s State and FULL Name, separated by space:" );
var namAr = namIn.split("");
var namArLen = namAr.length;


document.write(namAr + "<br /> Length:" + namArLen);



var i;
for (i = namArLen-1; i >=0;i--)
{
var result = document.write(namAr[i]);
}
</script> 


</body> </html>
```

you can use loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var namAr = namIn.split("");
```

try

```
var namAr = namIn.split("").reverse();
```

Comment: As it is homework, your teacher probably wants something that uses techniques of programming, like the loop answer.